# Agrupar datos por dos propiedades con librería lodash

Tags: javascript, typescript, group-by, lodash

Estoy usando `lodash` para agrupar un conjunto de datos, que son como estos:

```
confPersoDocenteClas = 
[
    {
        "id": 4582,
        "visible_cv_personalizado": false,
        "cv": "at8ow08swbv",
        "nombre": "testeocv",
        "id_user": 149
    },
    {
        "id": 4583,
        "visible_cv_personalizado": true,
        "cv": "at8ow08swbv",
        "nombre": "testeocv",
        "id_user": 149
    },
    {
       "id": 4584,
        "visible_cv_personalizado": true,
        "cv": "at8ow08swbv",
        "nombre": "testeocv",
        "id_user": 149
    },
    {
       "id": 4585,
        "visible_cv_personalizado": true,
        "cv": "a2er45tgdf1",
        "nombre": "testeocv",
        "id_user": 149
    },
    {
       "id": 4586,
        "visible_cv_personalizado": true,
        "cv": "a2er45tgdf1",
        "nombre": "testeocv",
        "id_user": 149
    }
]
```

Me gustaría poder agrupar por las propiedades de `nombre` y `cv` hago esto,

```
getConfigurcionPersonalizadaDocente(){
       this.confPersoDocenteClas = _.groupBy(confPersoDocente, "nombre_cv");
       console.log(confPersoDocenteClas);
       let data = _.groupBy(this.confPersoDocenteClas, "cv",)
       console.log(data);
}
```

En el primer `console log` me devuelve separado por nombres, pero en caso de que el nombre sea igual y tengan diferente propiedad de cv, se almacenan en el arreglo con el mismo nombre. En el segundo `console log` me devuelve agrupado como undefined todo y a mi me gustaría que ademas de almacenarse por el mismo `nombre` también se agrupen por el `cv` y obtener tener algo así:

```
testeocv: [
     {
        "id": 4582,
        "visible_cv_personalizado": false,
        "cv": "at8ow08swbv",
        "nombre": "testeocv",
        "id_user": 149
    },
    {
        "id": 4583,
        "visible_cv_personalizado": true,
        "cv": "at8ow08swbv",
        "nombre": "testeocv",
        "id_user": 149
    },
    {
       "id": 4584,
        "visible_cv_personalizado": true,
        "cv": "at8ow08swbv",
        "nombre": "testeocv",
        "id_user": 149
    }
]

testeocv: [
      {
       "id": 4585,
        "visible_cv_personalizado": true,
        "cv": "a2er45tgdf1",
        "nombre": "testeocv",
        "id_user": 149
    },
    {
       "id": 4586,
        "visible_cv_personalizado": true,
        "cv": "a2er45tgdf1",
        "nombre": "testeocv",
        "id_user": 149
    }
]
```

Que ya se encuentren agrupados por el valor del `nombre` y del `cv` Cómo podría hacer esto? Gracias de antemano